# What does this expression evaluate to? (bash shell script)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to do a code walk through a badly written bash script.

I have come across this statement:

```
FOOBAR_NAME=`date +WeekNo.%W`
```

There are no prior declarations of any of the RHS variables in the script, lines preceding this statement.

So my question is:

What does FOOBAR_NAME resolve to, when it is used a few lines down in the script as $FOOBAR_NAME ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no variables being referenced in the RHS.

The backtick operator (`` `) evaluates its contents and returns the output, similar (identical?) to`$()`.  It's a quick way to write an`eval` (in other languages).

Type `date +WeekNo.%W` in a shell.  What is printed (in stdout, with newlines collapsed) is what will be stored in `FOOBAR_NAME`.

Note that the evaluation occurs only once, which is during the assignment.  `date` isn't executed each time you reference `FOOBAR_NAME`.

Answer (score 3):

Try it!

```
$date +WeekNo.%W
WeekNo.30
```

Comment: curse you and your Ninja powers! +1 for being 33 seconds faster than me.

Answer (score 0):

See [man date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) for a description of the `date` command and it's formatting options. `%W` is week number.

Answer (score 0):

This is using a format string to the date command to create the a string that contains the week number.

The backticks execute the command between them; and the line assigns the result to the shell variable FOOBAR_NAME.

So if you really want to know what it does, just cut and paste the text between the `` into a shell and execute it.

Comment: @Anders, I call them backticks, and apparently others like @Recurse and @eje211 do as well.

Comment: @strager, Does not make it correct does it? Please read http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

Comment: @Anders: Many characters go by multiple names: `!`: "bang", "exclamation mark/point", etc., `*`: "splat", "star", "asterisk", etc., `#`: "pound", "hash", etc.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, Yes I know that, does not make it more correct either. Trying to follow a standard will make life a lot easier for everybody.

Comment: @Anders: Who's going to decide which of "period", "full stop", "point", "dot", etc. is more correct? And is it a "backquote" or a "grave accent"?

Comment: The pedantically correct term for the character is <code>grave accent</code>. Everything else is just a convenience, and which one is preferred varies from country to country and person to person.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in `man date`: If you specify an argument starting with `+`, then the rest of that argument is taken as a format string. The `Weekno.` part is taken literally, the `%W` does:

> %W     week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (00..53)

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator ("`=`") assigns the value on its right part to a variable on the left part. Here the variable is `FOOBAR_NAME`.

The right part is a subshell. The backticks ("`` `") create a subshell. The output of that subshell will go to the variable.

The subshell rurns the Unix `date` command. The manual page for all Unix commands is on the Internet. There [a Unix man page for date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date). Here, %W will be replaced by the number of the week.

So the variable gets the value "WeekNo" plus the number of the week.